# Overcoming issues with RKReachabilityObserver in RestKit

Tags: restkit

I posted recently about the [best way to implement RKReachabilityObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762710/best-way-to-implement-rkreachabilityobserver-in-restkit) (part of the [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) project) in my iOS project.

[mja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952753/mja) kindly informed me that there was a singleton available which I implemented at various points in my application. I set the kBaseUrl to an IP address to avoid DNS issues and tested with the following results:

- If the IP is reachable and the device has reception, the observer works as expected with only minimal delay.
- If 3G signal is available but the service can't be reached (happens a lot if you're on [Vodafone in the UK](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Network/Glasgow-3G/td-p/683545/highlight/true/page/10)), the observer takes a very long time to report its result and occasionally doesn't respond at all.
- When on WiFi and the network is busy/congested, the same behaviour as above is noted.

Is there anything I can do to improve the reliability of the RKReachabilityObserver from my end, perhaps via an alternative implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try to use the `Reachability` [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple. The class provides both getter and notification mechanism to determine and observe the changes in device's reachability status.

As for the RKReachabilityObserver, i think there is still work underway to enhance the operation. Can you indicate which iOS version do you run on the device?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using iOS 5 on the device. Is there an open case somewhere on github? I couldn't find one.

Comment: here is the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_frm/thread/e62521b70106a7e8/566683d76e5e9e34?lnk=gst&q=reachability#) in google group.